Express/Multer hang when receiving file upload request from Nextjs app
I'm learning about file upload flow between Nextjs app and third party api (in this case an Express server).
The flow suppose to go like this:
1.The user upload an image file via <input type="file"> then press submit which trigger server action (React's useFormState hook).
2.The server action receives formData object which contains the uploaded file. Now this is where I'm not sure if I did right. I want to upload the file inside the formData object to an Express app (which would then be processed and saved on a disk). So I used the following logic.
Next.js server action
export async function uploadImage(prevState, formData) {
   const imageFile = formData?.get("image");
   if (!imageFile) {
      return { success: false };
   }
   try {
      const response = await axios.post(
         "http://localhost:3002/uploadimages",
         formData,
         {
            headers: {
               "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            },
         }
      );
      return { success: true };
   } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading image:", error);
      return { success: false };
   }
}

Express.js endpoint with multer
app.post('/uploadimages', upload.single('image'), (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(201).json({
    message: 'Image uploaded successfully'
  });
});

Now the problem is every time I upload an image file this way, the server received the request but it hanged. The file seemed to show up in a directory I specified in multer setup. But all the files seem to be incomplete. The images were either blurred or partly missing.
I tried testing the endpoint with pure HTML, it works fine, the image showed up.
Is there specific behavior of Next.js that cause this?

Next.js server actions body limit size is 1MB,
You can configure the size limit from here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/serverActions#bodysizelimit
